# Where can I download help packages without help library manager for offline view for VS 2010

Tags: .net, visual-studio-2010

Is there an an available location to this packages? I want to download them via HTTP it will require time with my connection and I want to pause them when needed.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Some basic packages are located in Visual Studio distribution in **ProductDocumentation** folder.

If you need more packages, look at [Visual Studio 2010 Help Downloader](http://vshelpdownloader.codeplex.com/). It can download help for offline installation (can't pause though). It's also open source, so you can investigate where it downloads from.